# Binding dynamically created combobox to property on viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I'm looking to bind a ComboBox created at runtime to a property on the ViewModel.

I've tried something along these lines

```
combobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty,
    new Binding("WCSettings.ViewModels.WinCAPSIniViewModel.selectedItem")
    {
        Source = combobox.SelectedValue,
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
    });
```

The binding only needs to go one way (View --> ViewModel), so the value can be stored in a database.
'combobox' is the instance of the ComboBox being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the `SelectedValue` property of a ComboBox and at the same time setting the `Source` of the binding to the same property doesn't make sense.

You need to have an instance of the view model and use that as the binding source. And unless you also set the `SelectedValuePath` property of the ComboBox, you should bind the `SelectedItem` property.

```
WCSettings.ViewModels.WinCAPSIniViewModel viewModel = ...

combobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty,
    new Binding("selectedItem")
    {
        Source = viewModel ,
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
    });
```

And just in case you forgot, `selectedItem`  needs to be a public property in class WinCAPSIniViewModel.